# Remove duplicate rows from table except for first timestamp of each day

Tags: mysql, database, sql-delete

I need help removing un-needed rows from a table.

The table has user "check-ins" and some days have duplicates because of an early bug in software.

There should only be one entry per `uid`, per `lid`, per day (`timestamp`).

Sample data:

```
 id | t |uid| lid| timestamp
______________________________________
339 | 0 | 1 | 54 | 2014-03-28 16:02:05  <-- KEEP
341 | 0 | 1 | 54 | 2014-03-28 17:14:27  <-- DISCARD
420 | 0 | 1 | 54 | 2014-04-02 14:47:55  <-- KEEP
421 | 0 | 1 | 54 | 2014-04-02 15:15:04  <-- DISCARD
423 | 0 | 1 | 54 | 2014-04-03 11:06:36  <-- KEEP
427 | 0 | 1 | 54 | 2014-04-03 12:15:47  <-- DISCARD
428 | 0 | 1 | 54 | 2014-04-03 14:24:20  <-- DISCARD
470 | 0 | 1 | 54 | 2014-04-04 12:43:36  <-- KEEP
487 | 0 | 1 | 54 | 2014-04-04 14:34:38  <-- DISCARD
488 | 0 | 1 | 54 | 2014-04-04 14:36:41  <-- DISCARD
```

Would appreciate a MySQL `DELETE` command I can execute on my table to discard the rows (by `id`) that aren't needed.

Also, this should work on multiple `uid` and `lid` if possible.  If not, I can run in a script with a loop easily enough.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**updated** based on chat with OP:

try this :

```
DELETE a
FROM 
check-ins a
left join 
(  
  SELECT uid, lid, MIN(timestamp) AS min_time 
  FROM check-ins 
  GROUP BY uid, lid, DATE(timestamp)
 ) AS P
on 
(a.uid = p.uid AND
 a.lid = p.lid AND
 a.timestamp = p.min_time)  
where p.uid IS NULL
```

to explain : 
try the `select` statement first. This will return all the minimum dated timestamps per uid per lid.

```
SELECT uid, lid, MIN(timestamp) AS min_time 
FROM check-ins 
GROUP BY uid, lid, DATE(timestamp)
```

then you delete everything excluding these records.

Comment: @ScottN : yes, I made minor edit as I forgot to use `DATE` conversion in outer query.

Comment: Getting an error running this: `You can't specify target table 'checkins' for update in FROM clause`.  Any ideas?

Comment: `DELETE` command.  Seems `SELECT` is working just fine and I've verified it's selecting only the earliest record.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147175/discussion-between-scottn-and-prabhat-g).